# Most efficient way to clone a Bitlocker encrypted drive

Tags: bitlocker, windows-server-2012-r2

I need to replace the drive my Server OS is running with a bigger one.
That drive is encrypted with bitlocker.

I could either decrypt the drive (and all other drives on the server) or do a sector per sector clone which would take more time.

Which way is more efficient?

Comment: "Which way is more efficient?" - The only way correct way to clone the drive is to turn BitLocker off before you do so.